# Flex create unnecessarily row for link?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this demo : https://jsfiddle.net/5dypyf0h/
My problem is that i want to have link title in one row and verticaly align with text on left side. Any suggestion?

```
 <div class="explanation">
   <span>Ukoliko je adresa dostave drugacija od navedene adrese za naplatu, molimo unesite je</span>
    <a href="#" class="pull-right">UKLONI ADRESU</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I want that "UKLONI ADRESU" be in one row with using flex because i need to verticaly center text on left side with href link on right side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the floats (which don't work in flexboxes anyway) AND remove the widths.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/cwfnr3ed/1/)

```css
.explanation {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.explanation span {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.explanation a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #24282f;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* link text will not break */
}
```

```html
<div class="explanation">
  <span>Ukoliko je adresa dostave drugacija od navedene adrese za naplatu, molimo unesite je</span>
  <a href="#" class="pull-right">UKLONI ADRESU</a>
</div>
```